# pass json string to Post method

Tags: java, post, http-post

I have  a json string, I want to pass it to POST method. But the 'execute', and 'executeMethod ' are  throwing error as below:

"The method execute(HttpUriRequest) in the type HttpClient is not applicable for the arguments (PostMethod)". i have included the depencencies.

my code:

```
StringRequestEntity requestEntity = new StringRequestEntity(
            json-string,
            "application/json",
            "UTF-8");
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod("myUrl");
postMethod.setRequestEntity(requestEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(postMethod);
```

Is there any alternative way to do this? please help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I use [Apache HttpClient](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.2).
Snippet for calling a post method is as below.

```
String JSON_STRING="{"name":"Example"}";
StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(
JSON_STRING,ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://example.com/action");
postMethod.setEntity(requestEntity);
HttpResponse rawResponse = httpclient.execute(postMethod);
```

Comment: with Apache HttpClient also, i  am getting the same error, "The method execute(HttpPost) is undefined for the type HttpClient"